# Overall Avg and Avg. by in same query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Can I receive help on how to create a sql that includes the below?

I have two metrics that I want to show in the same query.

1. Avg
2. Avg summarized by

This should look something like the below table:

```
 Endpoint    OverallAvg     AvgbyEndpoint
 Red           25,000         20,000
 Green         25,000         30,000
 Yellow        25,000         25,000
```

My current code looks something like:

```
 let overallavg =
 requests 
 |extend  
 Endpoint = tostring(split(name, "/",2)[0])
 |summarize AvgDuration_seconds= avg(duration);
 requests
 |extend 
 Endpoint = tostring(split(name, "/",2)[0])
 |summarize AvgDuration_seconds= avg(duration) by Endpoint, overallavg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this:

```
let T = 
   requests
   | extend Endpoint = tostring(split(name, "/",2)[0])
;
let _overallAverage = toscalar(
   T
   | summarize avg(duration)
);
T
| summarize AvgByEndpoint = avg(duration) by Endpoint
| extend OverallAverage = _overallAverage
```